# The type or namespace name does not exists? (static class)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I've just started to create my website (from scratch with empty project) and I'm getting some errors however I'm really confused!
[image: Error]
**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="MonoLightTech.WebSite.Default" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>MonoLight Technology</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%= MonoLightTech.WebSite.Style.TestField %>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Style.cs** (BuildAction: Compile)

```
namespace MonoLightTech.WebSite
{
    public static class Style
    {
        public static string TestField = "MonoLight Technology";
    }
}
```

**Solution Hierarchy**

[image: Solution Hierarchy]

**Visual Studio:** *I also noticed, VS can see Style class and TestField member*

[image]

I'm a C# programmer already (desktop) and I'm sure, there is no problem with member access. I also *ReOpened* the project, *Cleaned* the solution and *ReBuilt* the project. What's wrong? Should be simple I think :)

**EDIT:** [Here is the solution project with all sources including all assets >>](http://monolighttech.com/WebSites.zip)

Comment: If `Style.cs` in the same project as `Default.aspx` ?

Comment: Is your project a Web *Site* or a Web *Application*?

Comment: @vcsjones It's "ASP.Net Web Application"

Comment: If you try to access that field in the code behind (run the code, don't trust IntelliSense), does it work? Ex: `var test = MonoLightTech.WebSite.Style.TestField;`?

Comment: @mason Still not works as you can see: http://prntscr.com/6hvydi/direct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I see what's wrong. I've changed back `Output path` from `.\` to `bin\` and it works. I really don't know why but this is the solution for me. Maybe someone can explain this later for us (I hope). And I think, *starting from scratch* not always the best way :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to include following line at the top of the page:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MonoLightTech.WebSite" %>
```

Comment: Still same. Btw, I'm already accessing classes in namespace with `MonoLightTech.WebSite`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if there are namespace issues with the page, but because you're namespacing Style.cs to the "MonoLightTech.Website" namespace explicitly, it may be that your Default.aspx only exists in the "MonoLightTech" namespace and so you'd need to drop an include statement at the top of the Default.aspx page like:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MonoLightTech.Website" %>
```

In order to have access to the field in the Style class.

Comment: Still same. I'm already accessing classes in namespace with `MonoLightTech.WebSite`, it might but not still not works.